# Check if header value match

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible to check the header value in Node.js? I would like to create a route that can be accessed only if the user supplies a header and its value matches what is coded. For example, suppose that route expect a header like `AccessKey: 12345` so it checks if there is such a header containing such value and if it doesn't match it throws an error. I tried to use something like `res.hasHeader()` like this:

```
app.route('/rest/api/here').get((req, res) => {
    if (res.hasHeader('AccessKey', '12345')){
          res.send('test') 
      } else {
          res.send('Header value doesn\'t match')
      }
    })
```

but it only checks if the header exists itself and doesn't check if the value match. Application is mostly for educational purposes so this approach is acceptable, if possible.

Comment: Assuming you're using express, you'd probably want to examine `req` as that is the request, not `res`, since that's the response. Then I'd check [the documentation for Request](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req) -- looks like [`req.get()`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.get) might be promising.

Comment: @heretic-monkey, your comment would make a great answer. That way the question could be counted on the home page as having answers, and the questioner can accept the correct answer if `req.get()` fills the bill.

Comment: @mlibby Yeah, sorry, didn't have time, and don't really know express well enough to be confident in the answer. I'm fine with someone else answering and getting the credit :). People should always be willing to take answers-as-comments and expanding them into answers-as-answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a library to parse the result, here is a complete example with comments to explain the parts. As the @Heretic Monkey pointed, out the token is on the request object, but thats not the approach i would use.

```js
// this is standard set of imports in app generated by
// express --no-view
// from package npm i -g express-generator
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

// token 'parsing' library
var bearer = require('express-bearer-token');

// more boilerplate
var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// look for the key in headers: { Authorization: AccessKey <your key> }
// this library also has options for query, body, etc... 
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-bearer-token
app.use(bearer({ headerKey: 'AccessKey' }));

// if present and what you wanted, proceed, else, fail
var protect = (req, res, next) => (
  (req.token && req.token === '12345')
    ? next()
    : next(new Error('bad token'))
);

// example protected (can protect a whole router with router.use(protect))
app.get('/protected', protect, (r, s) => s.json({ data: 'api' }));

// example not protected
app.get('/example', (r, s) => s.json({ not: 'protected' }));

// make sure to status 500 to make axios client throw
app.use((error, r, s, n) => s
  .status(500)
  .json({ error: (error + '') }));

// run the server
var server = app.listen(3000);

// client code (axios works in browser same exact api)
var axios = require('axios');

// wait until server started
setTimeout(async function() {
  // you will get status 500 without key on protected route
  try {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/protected');
    console.log('nope, wont see me print')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error for protected no token:', e.response.data.error);
  }

  // non protected works as expected
  var example = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/example');
  console.log('got example data fine: ', example.data);

  // for protected, need to supply header
  var protected = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/protected',
    headers: { Authorization: 'AccessKey 12345' }
  });
  console.log('got protected data fine w/tok: ', protected.data);

  // wait for server to shut down then exit the program
  server.close(() => console.log('bye'))
}, 500);
```